# linux driver compile error, cannot use $(shell pwd)/xxx as include path

Tags: makefile, compilation, linux-device-driver

When I compile my linux drive, I find a problem:

I have some ways to define the include path

A relative path by $(shell pwd), but it doesn't work:

```
MOD_INC=$(shell pwd)/include
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-I$(MOD_INC)
```

I found: $(shell pwd) == /home/myname/prj_svn

B abosulte path, it works:

```
MOD_INC=/home/myname/prj_svn/include
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-I$(MOD_INC)
```

C define a path, it works:

```
PRJ_PATH=/home/myname/prj_svn
MOD_INC=$(PRJ_PATH)/include
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-I$(MOD_INC)
```

I don't know why?

I try them in an application project, all of them can work.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, what is the current working directory when you run Make?

Comment: current directory is : /home/myname/prj_svn

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work"? What does it do? What does it add to `EXTRA_CFLAGS`?

Comment: "it doesn't work" means the header files in the include path cannot be found when the module is compiled.  EXTRA_CFLAGS just likes CFLAGS

Answer (score 1):

Make does quite a lot of directory changing as it builds; i wouldn't want to rely on the value of `pwd` at any particular point in time.

How about defining an environment variable called something like `MODULE_HOME`, set to `/home/myname/prj_svn`, and writing all your paths relative to that?

Comment: but if someone checkout my code, he has to change the define to compile.

Comment: You could set it from a shell script which drives the makefile. Something similar to this but more sophisticated happens with autoconf, which has [preset output variables](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Preset-Output-Variables.html) such as `top_builddir` which could be used here.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a good solution for this problem, thank you.